# How to create a Python integer array that returns the maximum

Tags: python, arrays

How can I finalize this Python integer array?

```
import array

# Function definition

def myFunc(myArray):
    print(myArray)

myArray = array.array('i', [for i in range(1, 1000)])
print(myArray)

myFunc(myArray)
```

The myArray has *n* integers, and it should return the maximum among all one-digit integers.

*n* is an integer from 1 to 100. Each element in myArray is within the range of -5 to 5.

Comment: Do you want an `array` or just a `list` like `numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?  Can you also give a sample output?

Comment: Its an array not list

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to build a list of random numbers from `[-5, 5]` from a range of 1 to `n` by following the example below.

To get the max number from the list, simply pass the list to the `max` function.

```py
import random

size = 10
value_min = -5
value_max = 5

arr = list(random.randrange(value_min, value_max + 1) for x in range(1, size))

print('List', arr)
print('Max', max(arr))
```